# Sending a lot of data from PC to Android via Wi-Fi

Tags: android, tcp, wifi

I've developed applications which handle a connection between a PC and an Android phone via [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi). I try to send a lot of data really often. The TCP/IP protocol, which I used, allow me to achieve just low speed - around 1 Mbit/s. I found that with [802.11n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) standard we can achieve speed up to 150 Mbit/s. I've set my router to use only 802.11n standard, but I didn't notice any improvement.

***What level of speed should be expected?*** I understand that part of data is lost, but is there any better solution? Any ideas? Where can I find some information to better understand this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You should expect much better performance running 11n with TCP/IP, perhaps 20 Mbit/s in a good environment. But since it is radio, the medium is shared between all users of the air so it is not easy to give a good answer that is valid everywhere.

A tool to test your network throughput is [Iperf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf) available on Google Market for your Android device and [on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/). You could use this to see if it is your application or external factors that might affect performance.

If you want to debug it further, you could use [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) together with a Wi-Fi sniffer card to see individual packets/transmission rates and retransmission.